# Hyperlink formula to report with multiple field

Tags: formula-field

I want to make a formula with a Hyperlink function in order to display a report in salesforce LEX with pre feel value.

I try to begin with this syntax  =>

```
HYPERLINK("#/sObject/00O58000004Rabl/view?fv0="&matching_Domaines_sans_virgules_1_2__c&"fv1"& matching_Localisation_MIA_sans_virgule__c,matching)
```

But it's not working.

I want to pass all this field. This example is used to a custom button

```
&fv0={!Opportunity.matching_Domaines_sans_virgules_1_2__c} 
&fv1={!Opportunity.matching_Localisation_MIA_sans_virgule__c} 
&fv2={!Opportunity.matching_Debut_au_plus_tot__c} 
&fv3={!Opportunity.matching_Debut_au_plus_tard__c} 
&fv4={!Opportunity.matching_Debut_au_plus_tot__c} 
&fv5={!Opportunity.matching_Debut_au_plus_tot__c} 
&fv6={!Opportunity.matching_Debut_au_plus_tard__c} 
&fv7={!Opportunity.matching_Debut_au_plus_tard__c} 
&fv8={!Opportunity.Dur_e_min__c} 
&fv9={!Opportunity.Dur_e_max__c} 
&fv10={!Opportunity.Dur_e_min__c} 
&fv11={!Opportunity.Dur_e_min__c} 
&fv12={!Opportunity.Dur_e_max__c} 
&fv13={!Opportunity.Dur_e_max__c}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missin  " = " and " & " signs inside your quotes.

Try this (check fv1 part)

```
?fv0="&matching_Domaines_sans_virgules_1_2__c&"&fv1="&.........
```